# openmp spmv CSR vectorization

Tags: vectorization, openmp, sparse-matrix, hpc

I've produced this kernel

```
struct csrFormat {
    int M, N;
    int *IRP;
    int *JA;
    double *AS;
};

struct vector {
    int dim;
    double *val;
};


double csrSIMDReduction(struct csrFormat *csr, struct vector *vec, struct vector *res, int nz){
    int M = csr->M;
    int nonzerosPerRow = nz/M;
    int chunk_size = 10000/nonzerosPerRow;
    
    double *val = res->val;
    
    struct timeval start,end;
    
    gettimeofday(&start, NULL);
    
    //IRP is the row_pointer array
    //JA is the column indices array
    //AS is the values array

    int i,j,tmp;
    #pragma omp parallel 
    {
        #pragma omp for private(i, j, tmp) schedule(dynamic, chunk_size)
        for (i=0; i<M; i++)
        {
            double result = 0.0;
            #pragma omp simd reduction(+ : result)
            for (j = csr->IRP[i]; j < csr->IRP[i+1]; j++)
            {
                tmp = csr->JA[j];
                result += csr->AS[j] * vec->val[tmp];
            }
            val[i] = result;
        }
    }
    
    gettimeofday(&end, NULL);
    
    res->dim = M;
    
    
    //printf("%ld.%06ld\n", start.tv_sec, start.tv_usec);
    //printf("%ld.%06ld\n", end.tv_sec, end.tv_usec);
    long t = (end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec)*1000000.0 + end.tv_usec - start.tv_usec;

    return (double) t;
}
```

but i'm having a doubt: how does the vectorization works?

I mean, from what i've understood, the inner cicle is runned running multiple iterations together, but how can a single thread do this?

EDIT: code updated.

Comment: Can you [edit] your code to be a [mre] -- knowing all types is relevant here. Your inner loop likely vectorizes quite well if you have AVX2s gather instructions available.

Comment: @Laci my question is not about the code, i'd like to understand how vectorization works on the CPU cores. I've undestood that the CPU needs to have AVX instructions available, but at register level, how can a single core stores multiple values (a vector) and perform a calculation that includes the entire vector in a single clock cycle?

Comment: Please read Agner Fog's [The microarchitecture of Intel, AMD, and
VIA CPUs](https://www.agner.org/optimize/microarchitecture.pdf)

Comment: Basically, AVX instructions work on vector registers, which store 8 floating point numbers, and so you can 8 operations in one cycle. Btw, sparse matrices usually have inner loops that are much too short for vectorization. You should mostly rely on parallelization of the outer loop.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout thank you, this is exactly what i wanted to know.

Comment: I see no need for the `reduction` clause, since `result` is local to each thread. (And it seems perverse to declare `i,j,tmp` outside the parallel region).

Comment: @JimCownie what's the difference between declaring them outside or inside?

Comment: Outside you need to remember to add them to the `omp parallel private(...)` directive to ensure that they are not shared in the parallel region. Inside you don't. So you can't forget to do that! It is generally good style to declare local variables in the minimum required scope. (Which has been possible since C99, so is hardla a cutting edege feature).

Comment: @JimCownie I think in theory the `reduction` clause is needed (as it corresponds to vectorization, not to parallelization), in practice, however, you do not have to use it as auto-vectorization works well and recognises this pattern.